# Obtener id de usuario ingresado laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy cargando datos desde un arhivo `excel` a mi `base de datos` pero en una `foranea` necesito llamar al `id`del usuario que esta logeado para poder registrarlo, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

Codigo controlador (import)

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    $id=Auth::tbl_usuario()->usu_id;

    $tipo=DB::table('tbl_tipo_instrumento')->select('tipo_id')->where ('tipo_nombre','=',$row[14])->get();
    $marca=DB::table('tbl_marca')->select('mar_id')->where('mar_nombre','=',$row[15])->get();
    $usu = DB::table('tbl_usuario')->select('usu_id')->where('usuario','=',$row[13])->get();

    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row[0],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row[4],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row[6],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row[1],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row[5],
        'ins_claseOexactitud' =>$row[6] ,
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row[7],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row[8],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row[9],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row[10],
        'ins_modelo' => $row[11],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row[12],
        'ins_area' => 'null',
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca,
    ]);
```

Pero al momento de cargar el archivo `excel` me sale el siguiente error :

`Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::tbl_usuario does not exist.`

Adicionalmente adjunto el `codigo` de mi modelo:

```
class tbl_usuario extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
 {
use Authenticatable;

public $timestamps = false;
public $table="tbl_usuario";

 }
```

Como podria solucionar ese problema, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con la documentación de Laravel, el usuario con la sesión activa se puede obtener de varias formas:

1. Con el facade Auth

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

   // Get the currently authenticated user...
   $user = Auth::user();

   // Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
   $id = Auth::id();
   ```
2. En un Request

   ```
   public function update(Request $request)
   {
       // $request->user() returns an instance of the authenticated user...
   }
   ```
3. Con el helper auth() (Similar al primero)

   ```
   $user = auth()->user();
   ```

En resumidas cuentas, usando el facade, el request o el helper, el método que deberías usar es `user()`

Comment: Disculpa mi modelo es tbl_usuario y mi tabla usuario su llave primaria es usu_id, yo no estoy usando la tabla por defecto que tienen los usuarios en laravel, la tabla que uso es una diferente

Comment: No tiene nada que ver, es información que está en la sesión.

Comment: Entonces en ese caso en mi controlador pondre `$id = Auth::id();` para recoger el id y luego `$id` lo pongo en el campo que quiero ingresar?

Comment: Es correcto, debería funcionar, a menos que hayas hecho alguna modificación importante en la forma como funciona Laravel.

Comment: Lo probe y no recoge el id, al momento de insertar me sale que el campo esta vacio y no puede ser nulo

Comment: Revisa primero qué entrega el método, si no funciona, entonces hay algo fuera del alcance de la pregunta que impide que funcione correctamente.

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez en tu modelo no veo que sobreescribas cuál es la llave primaria. Ya que no estás siguiendo ninguna de las convenciones de nombres de Laravel, vas a tener que hacer todo explícitamente, por ejemplo indicarle al modelo cual es su llave primaria con `protected $primaryKey = 'usu_id';`

Comment: Okey en mi controlador pongo lo siguiente  `$id = Auth::usu_id();` y luego ese `$id`lo llamo abajo en el campo pero me sale lo siguiente = `Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::usu_id does not exist.` @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez No, en tu **Modelo** agrega `protected $primaryKey = 'usu_id';` y en tu **Controlador** `$id = Auth::id();`

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias